# Natbib undefined error while using standalone

Tags: citing, natbib, standalone, subfiles

I am working on a project that is going to be fairly big.
I therefore decided to work with the *standalone* package.
I work in overleaf and my project is structured as follows:

```
->Main.tex
->Folder Chap 1
--->Folder Figures
--->Chap 1.tex
->Folder Chap 2
--->Folder Figures
--->Chap 2.tex
->ref.bib
```

I want to write the whole chapter in my *Chap 1.tex* and then simply import it via input it in my *Main.tex*.

My *Chap 1.tex* looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apa}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Nulla eget lacinia justo. Sed tincidunt elit nunc, 
vitae laoreet ipsum scelerisque et. 
Ut ex nisi, dapibus eget scelerisque vitae, 
varius in arcu\citep[][]{einstein2010}.

\end{document}
```

My *Main.tex* is as follows:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apa} 

\begin{document}

\input{Chap1/Chap1}

\newpage

\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

In my *ref.bib* I have the reference as follows:

```
@ARTICLE{einstein2010,
author = {A. Einstein},
title = {Sed tincidunt elit nunc},
journal = {Sed tincidunt elit nunc},
volume = {58},
number = {Issue 6},
pages = {31-40},
year = {2010}
}
```

How come the reference does not work for *Chap 1.tex*? It does find the reference but still gives an error when compiling. Do I have to put my *ref.bib* somewhere else? I simply want to cite in my *Chap 1.tex* and ultimately create a bibliography in *main.tex* of all references used in *Chap 1.tex* and *Chap 2.tex* and so on.

Comment: You would also need `\usepackage{subfiles}` in `Main.tex`. Note that `apa.bst` is no longer distributed in TeX Live, so BibTeX won't be able to resolve the citations. You may want to switch to `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}\bibliographystyle{apacite}` instead. Also, `\documentclass{standalone}` would typeset everything in `Chap1.tex` as one long single line if you're compiling `Chap1.tex`. Might the `subfiles` class and package be more suitable?

Comment: @LianTzeLim Thank you for your reply. This indeed fixed my problem. In regards to `\documentclass{standalone}`, you are right. It is not exactly one long single line when compiling `Chap1.tex`, but I can't indeed see the whole text (quite annoying). I would have to look into `subfiles` as I am entirely new to `subfiles` and `standalone`. Since I have quite a lot of tikz pictures with their respective `filecontents`, I decided to use `standalone`. Are you perhaps willing to help me with my transition from `standalone` to `subfiles`?

Comment: @imnothere Do you know why `apa.bst` is no longer distributed? Al my files used `natbib` with `apa.bst`. Do you know of any changes I have to make if I want to switch to `natbibapa`?

Answer (score 1):

*[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]*

`\documentclass{standalone}` works great if your Chap1.tex contains just a single `tikzpicture`; but if it contains other material e.g. paragraphs of text, then the resultant PDF may be just one (or a few) very long single line of output, when compiling just Chap1.tex.

The `subfiles` package and document class may be more suitable here; you can still use `standalone` for the `tikz` drawings. You can find more information about `standalone` and `subfiles` [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents#Separate_compilation_of_child_documents) and [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects).

In addition, `apa.bst` is no longer distributed in TeX Live, so BibTeX won't be able to resolve the citations as it can't locate the style file. You may want to switch to `apacite` instead.

Here's a small example comprising `main.tex`, `ref.bib`, `Chap1/Chap1.tex` and `Chap1/drawing1.tex`.

---

### main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}
\tikzset{special/.style={fill=cyan,ellipse}}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 

% From https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents#Subfiles_and_bibtex
% To get citations working in both the main and sub files
\def\biblio{\bibliography{ref}}
\begin{document}
\def\biblio{}

This is the main file!!

\subfile{Chap1/Chap1}

\newpage

\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

---

### Chap1/Chap1.tex

Doesn't need anything else in the preamble other than the `\documentclass[...]{subfiles}`; preamble from `main.tex` will be used. Paths inside this file are *relative to* `Chap1/Chap1.tex`.

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Nulla eget lacinia justo. Sed tincidunt elit nunc, 
vitae laoreet ipsum scelerisque et. 
Ut ex nisi, dapibus eget scelerisque vitae, 
varius in arcu \citep{einstein2010}.

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
\centering
\subfile{drawing1}
\caption{Hello World}
\end{figure}

\biblio
\end{document}
```

---

### Chap1/drawing1.tex

This is a `standalone` file for a `tikz` drawing. You'll need to add necessary TikZ settings in this file; nothing is read from main.tex when compiling just this file.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}
\tikzset{special/.style={fill=cyan,ellipse}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,special] (a) {Hello};
\node[draw,right=2cm of a] (b) {World};
\draw[->] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Compiling `drawing1.tex`:

[image: Compiling drawing1.tex]

Compiling `Chap1.tex`:

[image: Compiling Chap1.tex]

Compiling `main.tex`:

[image: Compiling main.tex]

---

(You can also compile your `standalone` drawings separately, download the output PDF, and then re-upload them so that you can use `\includegraphics` on them in your `Chap1.tex`. This would also help speed things up, if you have a lot of TikZ drawings.)

Comment: Thank you a lot for this amazing explanation.Extremely clear and very helpful. On the overleaf website the page [Multi-file LaTeX projects](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects) introduced me to `standalone` and `subfiles`, but it definitely wasn't clear how to optimally use both of them in a manner you described above (would definitely not hurt to put your explanation on Overleaf!). Once again many thanks!